# Unity3D- Can't get value of other gameobject's variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm re-asking this question because I screwed up while asking the first time. So here we go. I'm working on a Pokémon fangame, using Unity3d. I am currently working on health bars. the problem is that it can't find the value of a variable, which is attached to a separate game object. Here are the parts of my code that aren't working:

```
public Pokemon opponent;
public GameObject opponentTemp;
InitiateBattle opponentObject = opponentTemp.GetComponent<InitiateBattle>();

    print (opponentObject);
    opponent = opponentObject.PokemonToCatch;
    print (opponent.Name);

    TheirSlider.maxValue = opponent.Hp;
    TheirSlider.value = opponent.CHp;
```

(Note: Hp and CHp are parts of a class I made. If you need info on that I'll give you some documentation.)

What I'm trying to access is `opponentObject.PokemonToCatch`. I'm getting nothing when I try to reference it. I'm trying to reference it from another game object's script (hence the title of this question). It seems to work in this part of my script, though;

```
UserParty = GameObject.Find ("UserData"); 
    Party holdingPokemon = UserParty.GetComponent<Party>();

    MySlider.maxValue = holdingPokemon.currentPokemon [0].Hp;
    MySlider.value = holdingPokemon.currentPokemon [0].CHp;
```

To me, it just seems the same. Asides from this, this is really all I can find.
If you want the code for the `PokemonToCatch` variable, here it is:

```
WildPokemon PokemonEncounter = NativePokemon.GetComponent<WildPokemon>();
public Pokemon PokemonToCatch;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        //print (i);
        if (PokemonEncounter.CatchablePokemon [i].Find == GrassDat.TG){
            print ("hit");
            AvaliablePkmn.Add (PokemonEncounter.CatchablePokemon [i]);
            //AvaliablePkmn [i] = PokemonEncounter.CatchablePokemon [i];

        }
}
print (AvaliablePkmn.Count);
    int number = Random.Range(0, (AvaliablePkmn.Count + 1));
    PokemonToCatch = AvaliablePkmn [number];
    print   ("PokemonToCatchName:" + PokemonToCatch.Name);
    //print (PokemonToCatch.Model);
    PokemonToCatch.Model.transform.position = new Vector3 (30, 0, 5);
    PokemonToCatch.Model.transform.Rotate (0, 250, 0);
```

To sum it up, I'm trying to access `opponentObject.PokemonToCatch` from a script, but nothing is being found. It's empty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to learn how to ask questions properly. **"he problem is that it can't find the value of a variable, which is attached to a separate game object."** What variable? What game object? What script is that variable inside?

Comment: Your question has a little too much information. Could you post only the section of code where you're having trouble? Also some screengrabs of how your GameObjects are setup and scripts are attached might help clearing it up

Comment: `public Pokemon opponent;
public GameObject opponentTemp;
InitiateBattle opponentObject = opponentTemp.GetComponent<InitiateBattle>();

    print (opponentObject);
    opponent = opponentObject.PokemonToCatch;
    print (opponent.Name);

    TheirSlider.maxValue = opponent.Hp;
    TheirSlider.value = opponent.CHp;`
Is the part I'm having trouble with, to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide code for the variable you are trying to reference. Also saying "this block of code here all doesn't work" is really vague. What exactly isn't working? What value are you not getting?

All else aside, Assuming the Hp and CHp is what you cannot reference. The best answer I can give you is you need public accessors for the variable you are trying to access in the original script.

```
public float HP {get { return Hp;} protected set; }
public float CHP {get { return CHp;} protected set; }
```

That will let you publicly access the hp and CHp values outside the script and no allow you to set the value outside the script. If you need to change hp values you can make a function that is publicly accessible that sets the value inside the script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your opponent code is missing the equivalent of this line:

```
UserParty = GameObject.Find ("UserData");
```

Assuming you are using GameObject.Instantiate to create the opponent, it would be better to set opponentTemp at that time instead of using Find() so you don't have to worry about the name changing.

Comment: `UserParty = GameObject.Find ("UserData");` is a separate game object, that containing different values than what I'm trying to access. Still no luck. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I mean something like `opponentTemp = GameObject.Find("Squirtle_1");`

Comment: All the Pokémon data is stored in the `PokemonToCatch` variable, which I can't access.